# How to delete nodes from a xml document (Dom4J)

Tags: java, dom4j

Here is my code

```
public Document getNewFeedDocument(Document doc)  {

        Element root = doc.getRootElement();

        List<Node> nodes = doc.selectNodes("Message");

        for(int i=0; i<nodes.size(); i++) {
            String message_ID = ((Element)nodes.get(i)).selectSingleNode("MessageID").getText();
            if(Integer.parseInt(message_ID)%2==0) {
                nodes.get(i).detach();
            }
        }
        try {
            SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
            return reader.read(new StringReader(root.asXML()));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But this returns the same document, How can I get modified document.

Comment: your code tries to detach from List of Nodes,but you are returning back the original root without modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the selectNodes creates a temporary document. Iterate over the original doc:

```
private boolean toRemove( Node node ){
    if( ! "Message".equals( node.getName() ) return;
    String message_ID = 
        ((Element)nodes.get(i)).selectSingleNode("MessageID").getText();
    return Integer.parseInt(message_ID)%2 == 0;     
}

public void treeWalk(Element element) {
    for ( int i = 0, size = element.nodeCount(); i < size; i++ ) {
        Node node = element.node(i);
        if ( node instanceof Element ) {
            if( toRemove( node ) ){
                 node.detach();
                 i--;
            } else {
                treeWalk( (Element) node );
            }
        }
    }
}

treeWalk( doc.getRootElement() );
```

Comment: This will actually not go through every node, because you're detaching them in the middle of recursion. You'll also have to decrement `i` when detaching a node to account for the node at current index now having been removed and the remaining nodes having lower index. Otherwise whenever you detach a node, the next node gets automatically skipped by the check.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on decrementing i - edited. But I'm not sure why you think recursion should go into an element that is to be pruned from the tree anyway.

Comment: +1, now it's more useful. I didn't mean recursion should go into the pruned element, sorry if I gave that impression. Only wanted to comment about the looping by index and removing items in the middle of the loop, which changes the indexes of remaining items to be looped.

Comment: I'd probably do this using JAXB. Handling data in an object tree represented by POJOs is always easier than using the technical DOM API. YMMV

Comment: *shrugs* Depends on the case. If I need to remove a few tags from a large XML document and change a couple of others, I can do that with 50 lines of Dom4J or 500 lines and 10 new POJOs of JAXB. A whole lot more spaghetti code involved in the latter.